# Can I activate WSL 2 in latest Windows update 2004 without Insider or Beta Program?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just installed the public update 2020-04 KB4549951 and thought now WSL 2 should be included. But running

```
wsl -l -v
```

doesn't work as expected, so I think, I still have version 1. Is WSL 2 not included in the latest update? Or do I have to remove it completely and reinstall it?

Thanks in advance for clearification.

Bye The_Unknown

Answer (score 0):

Enable the VM platform.

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart
```

And then set the default version to V2?

```
wsl --set-default-version 2
```

Full guide here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#set-a-distro-to-be-backed-by-wsl-2-using-the-command-line